# spring boot mybatis check database connection

Tags: spring-boot, database-connection, mybatis

I am developing a spring boot app that uses myBatis for database.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It is possible to have some method or something to check that DDBB connection is OK? In app startup and also each X ms.
I know that i can do it with a batch process that check database connection for example performing a SELECT 1, but maybe there is another way more simple to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any connection pooling.?If yes,then there should be a mechanism to validate the connection before handing out to the application.

Comment: No I dont.... what do you recommend to use as pool connection? Hikari for example?

Comment: I havent used Hikari but it should support the validation of connections before acquiring.Check this https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby